# Maven 3 Parallel build Projects Skipped

Tags: maven-3, parallel-builds

Does anybody know of any reason why some of my projects are marked as SKIPPED at the end of a successful maven build?

please note that the 'skip chain' always starts with my web project which includes the following features:

- jspc-maven-plugin
- war plugin with overlay
- maven-dependency-plugin

Comment: It seems as though the web project build commences and at some point during the jsp compilation its discarded, the overall build process is marked as successful and the web project as skipped.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to OutOfMemoryError's inside Maven. We had similar problem with Maven skipping half of the modules. Increasing memory for Maven process itself solved the issue. I don't know if it is specific to some particular plugin behaving bad or to the Maven core.

Comment: Looks like it could be caused by any Error happening during the build.